# React native style SwipeListView

Tags: react-native, styled-components

im using SwipeListView in my react native app , when i swipe left two buttons appear one for delete and the other for update , the problem i have here is the height of those Hidden item  buttons are not like the size of rendreItem , i tried different ways to make it with same height but nothing works , i dont know what im missing
this is what i get
[image]

this this my code

```
const renderItem = (data) => (
    <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
      <View
        style={[
          styles.checkBoxContainer,
          data.item.done ? styles.checked : null,
        ]}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View>
          <Text>{data.item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
```

hiden Item

```
 const renderHiddenItem = (data, rowMap) => (
        <View style={styles.rowBack}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.actionButton, styles.updateButton]}
            onPress={() => updateItem(data.item)}
          >
            <Text style={styles.actionText}>Update</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.actionButton, styles.deleteButton]}
            onPress={() => deleteItem(data.item)}
          >
            <Text style={styles.actionText}>Delete</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      );
```

and this is how i render the items

```
<>
      <SwipeListView
        data={tasks}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderHiddenItem={renderHiddenItem}
        rightOpenValue={-150}
      />
    </>
```

and this is the style

```
cardContainer: {
    padding: 20,
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: colors.normalTask,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 12,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    elevation: 3, // For Android
  },

  checkBoxContainer: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  checked: {
  },
  rowBack: {
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "row-reverse", 
    padding: 20,
    height: "100%",
    },
  actionButton: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 75,
    
    height: "100%",
    
  },
  updateButton: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: "red",
  },
  actionText: {
    color: "#FFF",
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your actionButton style as:

```
actionButton: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: 75,
    height: "80%",
    marginBottom: 10,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on a blank page, if the others responses does not work for you, here is an updated style with a fixed height of 70

```
cardContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: "purple",
    flex: 1,
    borderRadius: 12,
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    elevation: 3, // For Android
    height: 70,
    },

  checkBoxContainer: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginRight: 10,
  },
  checked: {},
  rowBack: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row-reverse',
  },
  actionButton: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '100%',
    flex: 1,
  },
  updateButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  actionText: {
    color: '#FFF',
  },
```